# Обработка капчи средствами php - как быть?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, form

Есть скрипт который последовательно грузит файлы на сервер в группу вк.
Но проблема в том, что после 20 файлов выскакивает капча и не дает грузить дальше.
Можно ли как-то реализовать чтобы если в ответ сервер передал капчу - поставить скрипт на паузу, вывести окно с картинкой капчи и формой для ответа и после ввода и нажатия кнопки опять продолжить работать?

Я понимаю что нужно юзать формы, но не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать на практике...

Пример моего кода который отправляет:

```
$cou = 0;
foreach($dro as $current){
$put1 = dirname(__FILE__).'/src/'.$current;
//$post_data = array("file1" => '@'.$put1);
$post_data['file'] =  new CURLFile($put1);
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?group_id=".$group_id."&v=".$v."&access_token=".$token);
$url = json_decode($url)->response->upload_url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
$safe = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/docs.save?file=".$result['file']."&title=name_$cou&access_token=".$token."&v=".$v);
$kafe = json_decode($safe,true);
unlink($put1);
$cou++;}
```

Если скрипт возвращает капчу, то получаю ответ вида:

```
Array([captcha_sid] => 181337543764 [captcha_img] => https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=181337543764&s=1 )
```

Comment: Возвращать форму с этой капчей и продолжать с остановленного момента при следующем запросе

Comment: Можно хранить этот момент где угодно: в файле, в базе, в сессии, в куках

Comment: `Можно ли как-то реализовать чтобы...` - можно. Тут дело не в этом, мы не пишем за вас работу, а только помогаем. Если нужно чтоб написали, это на другие сайты, типа фрилансера.

Comment: @Ghost Ну вот я отправил файл - мне пришел массив. Но проблема в том что даже если я читаю массив и создаю под него форму - цикл переходит на следующую иттерацию и штампует мне так овермиллион форм с капчей для каждого файла, не дожидаясь пока я введу данные.

Comment: @Manitikyl Я и не прошу писать, а лишь объяснить в чем я не прав в моем алгоритме.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php вот эти команды могут вам помоч

Comment: @Mastas а по алгоритму что не так? Все нормально, так и будет работать) Когда вам придет капча, скрипт например создает файлик, где запоминает на какой картинке остановился, и выкидывает вам форму, вы ее вводите и все, скрипт берет файлик, и продолжает.

Comment: Можно и без файла, просто в форму с капчай отправлять ид картинки на которой остановился в инпут под хайдом, потом при отправки формы с капчай принимать этот ид и от него грузить дальше

Comment: В вашем случае простая задержка `sleep` поможет, либо же сделать сразу несколько токенов, и не париться по поводу капчи :)